# jQuery Error: Object has no method 'height', this.height()

Tags: jquery

I have a  with id `#list` and on click of some button I want to increase the size of all list elements by `50px`.

Why does the following code doesn't work:

```
function Test(){
   $("#list li").each(function(){
       var h = this.height() + 50;
       this.height(h);
   });
}
```

This function is activated on button click and on click I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'height' index.html:32
(anonymous function) index.html:32
b.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js:152
b.fn.b.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js:45
Test index.html:31
onclick index.html:44
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` is a DOM element. You want a jQuery object.

Try `$(this).height()` :

```
function Test(){
    $("#list li").each(function(){
        var h = $(this).height() + 50;
        $(this).height(h);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this. No need to loop:

```
function Test() {
    $("#list li").height(function (index, OldHeight) {
        return OldHeight + 50;
    });
}
```

The docs for `.height()` can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/height/#height-functionindex--height

Answer (score 1):

```
function Test() {
    $("#list li").css('height', '+=50');
}
```

Is the shortest answer I can think of, which could be extended to the following to make the function reusable for different elements and heights

```
function Test(el, height) {
    $(el).css('height', '+=' + height);
}
// usage
Test("#list li", 50);
```